# How to integrate this almost binomial distribution?

Tags: calculus

I want to evaluate

$$\int^{1}_{0}x^{k+1}(1-x)^{3-k} dx$$

Any ideas on how to do this?

I am just going to do it case by case since the problem only requires $k=0,1,2,3$ but I'd prefer a general result if possible.

Note, this isn't the problem itself. It's just a result I'd like to have a general form if possible because it would be cleaner than doing it case by case.

Comment: Is $k$ a positive integer? If so, the integral diverges for $k\gt 3$.

Comment: Yes, it is. $k$ can only be the numbers I listed

Comment: See the Beta function : $B(k+2\:,\:4-k)$ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html

Comment: Then, as you said, case by case. If you are curious about generalities, look at Wikipedia, **Beta Function**.